# How to set border for my li element in my case

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to create a 3 columns div.

I want my second column in my example to show a dotted border all the way to the bottom.

```css
#wrapper {
   
    background-color: yellow;
    top: 88px;
    left: 55px;

}

#wrapper li{
    width: 120px;
    height: 50px;
    padding-top: 15px;
}

#col1{
    display: table-cell;
}


#col2{
    border-left: dotted 2px grey;
    height: 100%;   
}


#col3{
    border-left: dotted 2px grey; 
}
```

```html
 <div id='wrapper'>
     <div class="row">
        <div id='col1' class="col-xs-4">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href=''>col-1</a>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>

        <div id='col2' class="col-xs-4">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href=''>col -2</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div id='col3' class="col-xs-4">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    row 1
                </li>
                <li>
                    row 2
                </li>
                <li>
                    row 3
                </li>
                <li>
                    row 4
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

JSFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/Mcq6u/17/

How can I do this? Thanks so much!

Comment: @MelanciaUK html, body, .row, #wrapper { height: 100%; } will stretch the #wrapper to the full page height, it doesn't seem that it is intended to be so.

Comment: @Arbel I've just noticed that. I'm tweaking it, but the idea is the same.

Comment: `#wrapper` has `top` and `left` defined, but no `position`.

Comment: you're not really making a 3 col layout correctly, so I'd recommend fixing your design & then it'll be easier to work on, follow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20566660/3-column-layout-html-css.  Then just add border-right or border-left to the example along w the rest of your customization & that should get you what you want.

Comment: @RandomUs1r not sure what is wrong with my layout. I need the responsive design so I need to follow bootstrap design layout

Comment: Oh, missed the bootstrap classes completely, in that case, try setting min-height: 100% & height: 100% on your li lags.

Comment: Based on this: http://www.minimit.com/articles/solutions-tutorials/bootstrap-3-responsive-columns-of-same-height You would achieve this: http://jsfiddle.net/Mcq6u/24/

Comment: There is another question that might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695784/how-can-i-make-bootstrap-columns-all-the-same-height

Comment: I just posted a quick solution. Let me know if it was what you were after. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add:

```
    .row{ 
         display:table-row;
    }

   .col-xs-4 {  
        display: table-cell;
        float: none; 
    }
```

**JSFIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/Mcq6u/29/

Comment: Right to the point. Can't upvote (daily voting threshold reached) but would do for sure.

Comment: Sorry dude. I'm not the OP. I was just around and curious about a quick solution.

Comment: I know, I noticed you were commenting around. I do the same sometimes, just read random questions. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can define a specific height to the columns. See this new code:

**CSS:**

```
#wrapper {
    background-color: yellow;
    top: 88px;
    left: 55px;
    height: 100%;  
    width: 100%;   
}
#wrapper li {
    width: 120px;
    height: 50px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    height: 100%;   
}
.row .col-xs-4 {
    height: 200px;
    width: 33%;
}
#col1 {
}
#col2{
    border-left: dotted 2px grey;
}
#col3 {
    border-left: dotted 2px grey; 
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
     <div class="row">
        <div id="col1" class="col-xs-4">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">col-1</a>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="col2" class="col-xs-4">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">col-2</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="col3" class="col-xs-4">
            <ul>
                <li>row 1</li>
                <li>row 2</li>
                <li>row 3</li>
                <li>row 4</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Mcq6u/26/

Answer (score 0):

why are you wrapping you content in ul and li?
(if you want dots you can just use a before pseudoelement)

using bootstrap's [specific classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/) for rows and columns (like you're doing) 
you could just use css:

```
   .col-xs-4 {
   border-left: dotted 2px grey;
   height: 100%;}
   .col-xs-4:first-child {border: none}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use css `display:table` to the container div and `display:table-cell` to your content divs

See the [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a1zpb8su/)