# multiple div alignment issues

Tags: html, css, alignment

I am trying to create multiple horizontal div elements on a page http://jsfiddle.net/bss6mc5a/

```
#body-left { float: left; content:url(http://placehold.it/240x930);}
#body { display: inline; }
#body-right { float: right; content:url(http://placehold.it/240x930);}
```

The layout is how I would like it to be displayed however when I add text (remove the comment tag) to the  the div  is moving down when I would like it to stay in place.

Thank you for any assistance / correction in how I achieve this.

Comment: just to clarify - the body div is moving the body-right div down, I would like the body-right div to not move when adding content to body.

Comment: 2 answers already, but for more information look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20566660/3-column-layout-html-css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define width for the divs:

```
#body-left { float: left; content:url(http://placehold.it/240x930);}
#body { float: left; width: 960px; }
#body-right { float: right; content:url(http://placehold.it/240x930);}
```

**Updated Fiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/bss6mc5a/3/

**Update 2:**

http://jsfiddle.net/bss6mc5a/7/

Comment: Thank you for the help so far, just to add to this -- I need the middle div to be 960px and the two side (body-left and body-right to say the same size and all centered)

Comment: @user3094178: I have updated the fiddle again .. check it .. http://jsfiddle.net/bss6mc5a/7/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to float your elements left or right, you can just set fixed location objects.

I updated [your JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/imattie/bss6mc5a/2/) to do what I'm thinking will help.

Basically, your left and right content areas would normally have fixed width (though your images make up for that), and would be positioned absolutely to put them in the right place, then the content is just centered with:

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 300px; /* some arbitary width */
```

But check out the Fiddle, see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

check this out I thing this what you want click [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uiupdates/bss6mc5a/4/)

Some changes in CSS

```
#body {
display: inline;
width: 960px;
float: left;
text-align: justify;
}
```

Hope this will help you...

Answer (score 0):

give your body divs a display: inline-block;

http://jsfiddle.net/bss6mc5a/5/

```
#body-left {content:url(http://placehold.it/240x930);display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;} #body { display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; width: 30%;} #body-right {content:url(http://placehold.it/240x930); display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;}
```