# How to make the sides of a website, with banners?

Tags: php

I made a website in PHP, and I wanted to make the sides of the website customisable and to use require (as footer.php and header.php) so I can place banners on them.

http://4st.me/4p3FQ.png

Anyone got an idea on how to make it? (If you require any code, please ask)

Comment: Let's see the code you tried to reproduce it with and failed. We won't write code for you. As it stands, is a very broad subject.

Comment: possible duplicate of [3 column layout HTML/CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20566660/3-column-layout-html-css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You need 3 column layout.** You have to make layout in HTML and CSS. You can try to do it like this:

[3 column layout HTML/CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20566660/3-column-layout-html-css)

And this is not question about PHP. It is about HTML and CSS. PHP is language used to generate HTML code for browsers.

You should read or watch some youtube tutorials about HTML, CSS and PHP. Maybe search for "The New Boston" or "PHP Academy" on youtube, they have not bad tutorials.

Comment: OMG, didn't know it's that hard... I quess I will leave it after I go college and learn how to do it :P Thanks anyway (But I will still try and maybe... I will make something)

Comment: You could just use HTML table with 3 columns, but this is very bad habit and ancient approach.