# print data in 3 columns with css

Tags: css

I want to print my data in 3 columns. But the data is not arranged correctly in the columns.
I have limited knowledge on CSS.
Please advice where I did it wrong?

I need to print a horizontal line in the third column afer 6 and 8.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.container{
    width: 596px;
    float:left;
    posy
}
.container .line {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #999;
    border-top-style: none;
    margin: 7px 0;
    padding: 3px 0 0;
}
.col1{

    width: 186px;
    right-padding:19px;
    float:left;
}
.col2{

    left: 205px;
    right-padding:19px
    width: 186px;
    float:left;
}
.col3{

    left: 410px;
    width: 186px;
    float:right;
    right:0px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="col1">
<ul>
<li>Test Area 1</li>
<li>Test Area 2</li>
<li>Test Area 3</li>
<li>Test Area 4</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="col2">
<ul>
<li>Test Area 5</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="col3">
<ul>
<li> Test 6</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="line"></div>
<div class="col3">
<ul>
<li>Test Area 7</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="col3">
<ul>
<li>Test Area 8</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="line"></div>
<div class="col3">
<ul>
<li>Test Area 9</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="col3">
<ul>
<li>Test Area 10</li>
</ul>
<div class="col3">
<ul>
<li>Test Area 16</li>
<li>Test Area 17</li>
<li>Test Area 18</li>
<li>Test Area 19</li>
<li>Test Area 20</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col1">
<ul>
<li>Test Area 11</li>
<li>Test Area 12</li>
<li>Test Area 13</li>
<li>Test Area 14</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="col2">
<ul>
<li>Test Area 15</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</html>
```

[image: This is what I get.]
[image]

Comment: Your example has a few issues with invalid syntax. Your HTML is missing a closing body tag, and you have CSS elements that don't exist. E.g. `right-padding` should be `padding-right` etc.

Answer (score 2):

This question is similar to the one here: 
[how to split the ng-repeat data with three columns using bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21644493/how-to-split-the-ng-repeat-data-with-three-columns-using-bootstrap)
And here: 
[3 column layout HTML/CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20566660/3-column-layout-html-css)

There are several solutions. You could also use this css:

```
li:nth-child(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you have multiple `col1` divs, multiple `col2` divs, etc? I think your code would be better laid out with just one of each. It will make layout much clearer.

For example:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="col1">
    <ul>
      <li>Test Area 1</li>
      <li>Test Area 2</li>
      <li>Test Area 3</li>
      <li>Test Area 4</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>Test Area 11</li>
      <li>Test Area 12</li>
      <li>Test Area 13</li>
      <li>Test Area 14</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col2">
    <ul>
      <li>Test Area 5</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>Test Area 15</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col3">
    <ul>
      <li> Test 6</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <ul>
      <li>Test Area 7</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>Test Area 8</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <ul>
      <li>Test Area 9</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>Test Area 10</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>Test Area 16</li>
      <li>Test Area 17</li>
      <li>Test Area 18</li>
      <li>Test Area 19</li>
      <li>Test Area 20</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've made some additional changes with a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/nsqeLha4/

Comment: Hi, I want to make the code flexible, so that if the logic changes, data goes in correct columns depending on the div.

Comment: Checked your example. Data is getting set in rows. Dats not what i want to do. Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand the question, then. Could you perhaps mockup an image of the layout you want?