# Updating css properties real-time using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two division classes in my responsive site: section_left1 and section_right1

section_right1 flows very well with the document, but section_left1 is the problem.
Each time the document is ready or browser has been resized, i want to pass the height of section_right1 to section_left1.

How can i change the css properties with jquery or some other easy way?

Comment: You would use other css properties to achieve the goal. Like the [three column answer][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20566660/3-column-layout-html-css

Comment: Can include `html` , `css` , `js` at Question ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally you would use

```
var height_foo = $('#selector_foo').height();

$('#selector_bar').css({
    height: height_foo,
    color: green
});
```

Is there any problem with using this approach?

PS. Obviously you can update `height_foo` on window resize, or scroll or whatever you need. You're really flexible...

Answer (score 1):

You would use other css properties to achieve the goal. Like the [three column answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20566660/3-column-layout-html-css).

```
.column-left{ float: left; width: 33%; }
.column-right{ float: right; width: 33%; }
.column-center{ display: inline-block; width: 33%; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with regular Javascript:
(this method uses ID's, not classes)

```
x=document.getElementById('id');
x.style.height='123px';
```

This is according to [W3](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp).

Or, you can use JQuery:

```
$('.class').css({
 height: 120px;
 color: 'red';
});
```

There are multitudes of other possible ways to do this, but these are the easiest.

Hope that helps!