# How can I correctly type css float?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get my `div`s to be side by side, so that the first and the second would be side by side and so on..

I cant seem to get it looking like that.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>USS Vaja 4</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <style>
    p 
    {
        color: rgb(100,40,15);
        font-size: 16px;
        text-indent: 35px;
        font-family: verdana;
    } 
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<h1 style="color:#A05E03;text-transform:uppercase;">Lorem ipsum</h1>
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="http://uss.feri.um.si/">USS</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://feri.um.si/">FERI</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://dk.um.si/">DKUM</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="vsebina">
  <div id="slika"></div>

  <div id="prvi" class="vrh">
    <h2>Odstavek 1</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</span> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea <span class="commodo">commodo</span> consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="drugi" class="vrh">
    <h2>Odstavek 2</h2>
    <p><span class="lorem">Lorem ipsum</span> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea <span class="commodo">commodo</span> consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="tretji" class="dno">
    <h2>Odstavek 3</h2>
    <p><span class="lorem">Lorem ipsum</span> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea <span class="commodo">commodo</span> consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="cetrti" class="dno">
    <h2>Odstavek 4</h2>
    <p><span class="lorem">Lorem ipsum</span> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea <span class="commodo">commodo</span> consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="peti" class="dno">
    <h2>Odstavek 5</h2>
    <p><span class="lorem">Lorem ipsum</span> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea <span class="commodo">commodo</span> consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p><span class="lorem">Lorem ipsum</span> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea <span class="commodo">commodo</span> consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="sesti" class="dno">
    <h2>Odstavek 6</h2>
    <p><span class="lorem">Lorem ipsum</span> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea <span class="commodo">commodo</span> consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p><span class="lorem">Lorem ipsum</span> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea <span class="commodo">commodo</span> consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is my css file:

```
h2
{
    background-color:DarkOrange;
    font-family:arial;
    font-variant:small-caps;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:0px 0px 0px 22px;
    font-size:20px;
    color:white;    
}

ul
{
    list-style:url('pika.png');
}

.commodo
{
    font-weight:bold;
    font-style:oblique;
}

#prvi
{
    text-align:justify;
}

#drugi
{
    text-align:center;
}

a:link
{
    color:#B96600;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:18px;
}

a:visited
{
    color:#B96600;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:18px;
}

a:hover
{
    color:red;
    text-decoration:underline;
    font-size:18px;
}

a:active
{
    color:#B96600;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:18px;
}

div
{
    width:300px;
    margin:0px 20px 0px 20px;
    padding:5px 10px 0px 10px;
}

div#prvi, div#drugi
{
    border:4px dashed silver;
    height: 220px;
}


div#prvi>p, div#drugi>p
{
    height:150px;
    overflow:scroll;
}

#prvi 
{
    float: left;
}

#drugi 
{
    float: left;
}

#tretji 
{
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}

#cetrti 
{
    float: left;
}

#peti 
{
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}

#sesti 
{
    float: left;
}
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: Related: [3 column layout HTML/CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20566660/3821804)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look here for a super-simple solution. 
http://learnlayout.com/inline-block.html

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may use something like this:

```
.myDiv1{
float:left;
}
.myDiv2{
float:left;
}
```