# Really need help on div tags

Tags: html, css

I am taking a class on web design, and I have an assignment to set up `<div>` tags to resemble the layout below:

[image]

I've learned the basics of HTML and CSS on Codeacademy, but I haven't used those skills in awhile. Here's what I have so far:

```css
#banner {
  width: 698px;
  height: 71px;
  background-color: #8B4789;
  display: inline-block;
}
#button {
  width: 306px;
  height: 71px;
  background-color: #ff7373;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
  <title>
  </title>
</head>

<body background="Website comp.png">
  <div id="banner"></div>
  <div id="button"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Unfortunately, I'm a bit lost at this point, and from what I've researched, the advice I've gotten have given me mixed solutions that don't necessarily work well with each other.

How can I fix my code so as to resemble the given layout?

Comment: This could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20566660/3-column-layout-html-css

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Word to the wise for the future: half this question is fluff that doesn't matter and it's hard to tell if there is an actual question here. We don't need to know about your class, or that you are stressed - just leave this out and get to the meat. You'll get better answers that way. That being said, nevermind's comment will point you in the right direction.

Comment: Don't use set widths if you can help it, use percentages or even `rem`. This is a world of _responsive design_. Divs that need to be next to one another should be floated or use `flexbox` if not concerned about legacy browser support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very simple solution is to split the divs in parts of 100%. and set the height of all the top divs to the same height.

```
#banner{
    width:30%;
    height:30px;
    float:left;
}
```

do the same for, home (15%), about me (15%), career (15%) and schooling(15%).

After that do the same for the second line. I suggest you to make aparent div for *main-topic* and *text*.

Answer (score 0):

The platform bootstrap splits the screen into 12 columns for easy layout, and provides pre-built classes for stuff like nav-bar and jumbo-tron.

You just link bootstrap with cdn:

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

in your head and your body looks something like this:

```
<div id =  navbar>
    <div class = "row col-xs-12">
        <div class = col-xs-3>
            Banner
        </div>
        <div class = col-xs-3>
            Home
        </div>
        <div class = col-xs-3>
            AboutMe
        </div>
        <div class = col-xs-3>
            career
        </div>
        <div class = col-xs-3>
            Schooling
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "row col-xs-12">
        <div class = "col-xs-2">
            <div>
                <a>mainoTopic</a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a>Text</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class = "col-xs-8">
            <div>
                <a>Picture</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class = "col-xs-2">
            <div>
                <a>Explaining</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```